# Looking to implement Lab Environments in Test Manager and Need Pros and Cons

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

First off, please forgive me if I'm posting off topic here.

I recently been giving the task to come up with a strategy to incorporate Lab Management in Test manager. Before I go down the road of leading the project manager and CTO into a "Rah Rah" cheer leading session of Lab Management, I would like to find any objective articles or testimonials of the pros, cons, pitfalls, and best practices of integrating this. If anyone has any personal experience (Positive or negative) with Lab Management or if anyone knows any resources where I can get an objective view of Lab management I would be appreciative.

So far if I decide to implement this I'll more than likely use a standard lab environment opposed to a SCVMM environment. The reason being is that VMWare is already being utilized quite a bit in out organization and I would most likely set up my Lab VM's using VMWare.

Thanks in advance,
Dean